# how to get Datagridview selected cells in ordered by their column

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a table with columns c1 .. c4 and with a row containing data such as

c1 c2 c3 c4

[CAN][YOU][HELP][ME]

Multiselect is on. When I get datagridview.SelectedCells then they will be in the list in order of when they were selected. E.g. I select HELP and then YOU the list will be HELP followed by YOU. However I need a list to show YOU,HELP because YOU is from a column before HELP. If I would select YOU,HELP,CAN in that order then the list should be CAN,YOU,HELP because CAN is in c1, YOU in c2 and HELP in c3.

How can I do this? Thank you for your help.

Chris

Hi here is the code. The order of the selected cell list depends on how you select them - e.g. start left to right or vice versa. As you can see from the code, I have found a workaround. The OrderBy idea is much more elegant but I believe it only works for Rows and not for cells.

private void attribute_treeview_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // dropped item from either datagridview into treeview

```
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(List<string>)))
        {
            // Determine which category the item was draged to
            Point p = attribute_treeview.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            TreeNode destinationNode = attribute_treeview.GetNodeAt(p);

            // sort selected cells based on position in productname
            var selected_cells = e.Data.GetData(typeof(List<string>)) as List<string>;
            SortedDictionary<int, string> orderedcellcontents = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

            ProductItem pitem = new ProductItem((BsonDocument)productlist.SelectedItems[0].Tag);

            foreach (var element in selected_cells)
            {
                int pos = Array.IndexOf(pitem.tokens, element);
                if (!orderedcellcontents.ContainsKey(pos))
                    orderedcellcontents.Add(pos, element);
            }

            if (PopulateTreeview(destinationNode, orderedcellcontents.Values.ToList<string>())) 
            {
                dictionary_haschanged = true;
                destinationNode.Expand();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using linq to order them on index

```
var ordered = datagridview.SelectedCells.OrderBy(c=>c.Index)
```

**Edit 1:** so the above doesn't seem to work. Below I've created a small forms app to test.
The app consists of a form with a datagridview on it, a button and a textbox.
Clicking the button will display the selectedcells in their correct order in the textbox.
See the button1_click event for the sorting.

Forms1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var data = new List<Data>();
        data.Add(new Data { A = "CAN", B = "YOU", C = "HELP", D = "ME" });
        data.Add(new Data { A = "CAN", B = "YOU", C = "HELP", D = "ME" });
        data.Add(new Data { A = "CAN", B = "YOU", C = "HELP", D = "ME" });
        data.Add(new Data { A = "CAN", B = "YOU", C = "HELP", D = "ME" });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedCells = dataGridView1.SelectedCells;
        var array = new DataGridViewCell[selectedCells.Count];

        selectedCells.CopyTo(array,0);
        var sorted = array.OrderBy(c => c.ColumnIndex);

        var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sorted.Select(c => c.Value));
        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

Copying the cells to a DataGridViewCell array will let you sort it on the index.

Comment: tried that but I get the compile error that "DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection does not contain a definition for OrderBy and no extension method OrderBy accepting a first argument of type DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection " suggesting there is a using directive or assembly reference missing. I did define using System.Linq; what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate the problem? It gives indeed a compilation error, however I've tried with just doing datagridview.SelectedCells and this gives me back the list of cells in the order they appear on the screen, not in the order they are selected.

Comment: Hi here is the code. The order of the selected cell list depends on how you select them - e.g. start left to right or vice versa. As you can see from the code, I have found a workaround. Your OrderBy idea is much more elegant but I believe it only works for Rows and not for cells.

Comment: So the code you posted sorts it in the correct order? If so, can you also post the code when it didn't work. I'm curious as why for my test I get the selectedcells in the order they appear and not in the order I selected them as you stated happens for you.

Comment: no different code really. what I can see in "selected_cells" (the original data from the datagridview) is that if I have a row with A, B, C and if I select from left to right, then I will get a list C,B,A. If I select from right to left I will get A,B,C. can you see the same? my workaround is working fine as longs as the cell values are all different. if one is a duplicate then it will not add to the sorted dictionary and I loose. that value. I still need to solve that so that if I have A,B,C,A I don't get A,B,C but get A,B,C,A no matter what. any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my original answer with an example of how I achieved ordering the selected cells.

Comment: done - if you you are interested have a go at my other issue Datagridview selecting cell with mouse not working after DragDrop thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I think this is much easier/cleaner/shorter.

```
datagridview.SelectedCells
    .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
    .OrderBy(c=>c.ColumnIndex)
```

Comment: Instead of just posting one line of code, could you please explain what this code does, where it should be placed, and why does it solve the problem?

Comment: It is what DieterC in the accepted answer suggested at first but then he found out that it does not work, because he was missing a cast and then he did a solution with copying the array. It is a direct answer to the original question "how to get Datagridview selected cells in ordered by their column".